# How to get wix chat channel Id when user enterto my website

Tags: javascript, velo

I want to get channel Id so I used [corvid documentation](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-chat-backend.html#sendMessage) and follow instructions

First I added wix chat app 
then I added the following function :

```
 export async function  wixGetChannelId() {
 let channel = await $w("#myChatbox").getChannel({type: "Business"});
 console.log("channel id",channelId) }
```

and call wixGetChannelId function from `onReady`

But I got undefied, what I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried the below code to loop for the channel id.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    setInterval( () => {
        getId();
    }, 1500);
});

function getId() {  
    $w("#wixChat1").getChannel({type: "Business"})
    .then((channel) => {
        console.log(channel);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Basically, I get error the first few times (you are receiving the undefined because you dont catch the error) but as soon as I click on the chatbox icon (which I think triggers the creation of the channel) I start getting the channel information.

So I think the user needs to first initiate a conversation which triggers a new channel creation.

Comment: You right , user needs to first initiate a conversation which triggers a new channel creation, there is option to get channel id without sending first chatBox msg?

Comment: I don't think so. I have not been able to get a channel id without initiating a chat first.